# C# post using xcsrf token

Tags: c#, xml, odata, httpwebrequest, csrf

I am trying to post XML data using C# fetching `x-csrf-token`.

Am able to fetch token using get method and when I try to post I am getting 403 error.
Please assist me if I am wrong

```cs
string Token = "";
public string Postdata = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <entry xml:base='http://server:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCUST_TESTING_SRV/' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices'> <content type='application/xml'><m:properties><d:Kunnr>55556697</d:Kunnr><d:Land1>abi</d:Land1><d:Name1>abh</d:Name1><d:Name2>chaitanya</d:Name2><d:Ort01>kennedy</d:Ort01><d:Pstlz>500060</d:Pstlz><d:EStatus>X</d:EStatus></m:properties></content></entry>";
public string URL = "http://server:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCUST_TESTING_SRV/post_cust";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml,application/atom+xml";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["x-csrf-token"] = "Fetch";
HttpWebResponse responseH = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Token = responseH.Headers["x-csrf-token"];
//xcookies = responseH.Headers["set-cookie"];
responseH.Close();

// Here I'm creating Post Method ...
string requestString = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(data); //XMLDoc is the XML data string being submitted.
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Postdata);
HttpWebRequest request_post = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request_post.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request_post.Method = "POST";
request_post.ContentType = "application/xml";
request_post.Accept = "application/xml";
request_post.Headers["x-csrf-token"] = Token;
request_post.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request_post.KeepAlive = false;
Stream dataStream1 = request_post.GetRequestStream();
dataStream1.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream1.Close();
HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request_post.GetResponse();
dataStream1 = response1.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(dataStream1);
string responseFromServer1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();
reader1.Close();
dataStream1.Close();
response1.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry,questions: 1) What is the "method" URL? 2) Your Postdata variable becomes a postdata variable? Are you using the same variable?

Comment: Hi , Sorry that is not method that is url, even then I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything wrong with your code. Just posting some general tips:

- Are you sure about the NetworkCredential Username/Password?
- Try to see if simulating a browser will make a difference, e.g.:

  request_post.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
- Check if your request params and headers are correct (Accept,
  ContentType)
- Can you successfully do this request some other way? Are you trying to
  imitate a web app's behavior? You can use that web app and see the
  request and response data/headers using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and make sure
  all the headers are correct (including cookies).

Comment: I'm able to do it in Rest API and also Android, but with this C# I'm not able to post the same data. As per my knowledge I thought Token is not getting validated. It says 403 forbidden. help me

Comment: Check Fiddler out first with the successful REST request and with this unsuccessful request so you know which data you are sending differently.

Comment: I'm not using it on device I'm only trying it on Visual Studio 2013      C# Windows Form Application. please help me.

Comment: Well if you don't know what the right request data should be I don't think there's any way for me to help you. Your site's internal as well so I can't help you